Does Ontario effectively give 2.5 years for Small Claim Plaintiffs to write their Statement of Claim?
I quote Border Ladner Gervais LLP -

The Limitations Act, 2002 (the Act), which came into force in Ontario on Jan. 1, 2004, introduced a basic 2-year limitation period that is subject to the doctrine of discoverability. The Act also introduced an ultimate limitation period of 15 years, which is not subject to discoverability and begins to run from the “day on which the act or omission on which the claim is based took place.”


A claim should be served on each defendant within six months after the date it is issued.


After the Plaintiff’s Claim is issued, it must be served, personally or by an alternative to personal service, on each of the Defendants within 6 months of the date that the Plaintiff’s Claim was issued (Rule 8.01).

Suppose that January 1 2023 is the “the day the act or omission on which the claim is based took place, unless the contrary is proved”, according to s. 5(2).
Can’t a plaintiff file, and pay for, the small claim online on Dec 31 2024 ― to get her foot in the door ― but take until June 31 2025 to serve any claim? I ask, as a plaintiff can need the additional 6 months to write the Statement of Claim, or find a lawyer to write it, or decide whether to pursue a claim. As explained in this Reddit thread, lay people can take more than two years to discover medical negligence.

The entire legal proceedings may cost 6-figures, but it most certainly does not cost 6-figures to file pleadings, which is all the statute of limitations is concerned with. Those are boiler-plate documents that a lawyer can draft relatively quickly.


Note that the 2 year rule runs from when the claim accrues (basically when you know that it happened and who did it), which could be up to 15 years after the events in question (which is what "subject to the doctrine of discoverability") means. Also, as a practical matter, getting something on file is a much bigger deal than refining the statement of claim (which can probably be amended even after it is served).

The statement of claim must be filed within 2 years
You then have up to 6 months to serve it on the defendant- it must be the same claim so you can’t change it within that time.
Note that the initial 2 years runs from the point where the event that is the subject of the claim becomes known or should become known to a reasonably diligent plaintiff. Note that a latent defect may not be knowable until it fails and causes damage.
A Statement of Claim is a relatively short document stating the facts the plaintiff will prove, the legal basis of the claim, the damage suffered and the relief sought. It is very much a ‘starting gun’ for the suit and a lot more stuff will be provided later.
